# Apache PDFBox 2 Farsi/Arabic Text Extraction Issue with Some Characters (Wrong Output)

Tags: java, pdfbox, arabic, text-extraction, farsi

I am using Apache PDFBox 2.0.11 to extract text out of some PDF documents using the `PDFTextStripper` class. Here is the code used for extraction:

```
String pdfFilePath = "path/to/file.pdf";
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
try {
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(new File(pdfFilePath), "r"));
    parser.parse();
    cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
    String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);

    System.out.println(parsedText);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A big issue I've encountered is that PDFBox extracts some of the words incorrectly (mostly misplaced or totally missed characters). Especially, when it comes to "La" (in farsi: **لا**) it almost certainly goes wrong.
As a test case I've used a PDF file containing a few simple words ([test-file.pdf](https://mega.nz/#!39BwXQ4a!bHZ0-Fk5wlN3ZSeQj1koYqDrP3oKQYuzULn6S9huSak)). In the following table, the original words and PDFBox output is given:

[image]

So it would be quite helpful if anyone could provide some workaround for the described problem.

Comment: The **ToUnicode** table for the font in question in your PDF contains multiple mappings from different glyphs to the same Unicode code point. While this can make sense (the same character may be written differently depending on factors like its position in a word), PDFBox to a certain extent expects **ToUnicode** mappings to be injective and, therefore, runs into issues like it does with your document. (By the way, some other libraries also have issues with such mappings, not only PDFBox.)

Comment: Well, do you think it could be fixed by implementing a custom parser class (which inherits from the original PDFBox parser) specialized for Farsi and stuff?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Adobe Reader could successfully extract all the words. Thus, a custom parser class should be able to do so to. I don't remember, though, where exactly pdfbox implicitly required the **ToUnicode** maps to be injective, so I cannot tell how much you can inherit.

Comment: This issue is reported for PDFBox here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4531